# Problemas ao acrescentar script do Spotify com reactJS

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Eu estava tentando linkar o script da API do spotify no componente do React, mas quando vou usar a função "window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady" ele mostra o erro:"property onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady does not exist on type 'Window & typeOf globalThis", como se não reconhecesse o script.Como posso resolver isso ?

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function SpotifyPlayer() {

    useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
      // do your spotify magic here.
    }
    }, []);
      
}

export default SpotifyPlayer;
```

OBS: o HTML principal está em uma pasta e o componente em outra, mas já tentei colocar o script tag no body do html principal e, ainda assim, ele não reconheceu a função no componente.

Answer (score 0):

`onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady` não é uma propriedade do `window`, e como TypeScript tenta manter o seu código consistente com os tipos declarados, ele não está deixando você atribuir um valor para uma propriedade que ele não conhece.

Mas não tem muito o que fazer nesse caso, idealmente esse módulo teria que te dar um callback que não precisasse ser exposto no `window`, porém como ele funciona assim, você vai ter que fugir um pouco da metodologia do TypeScript para inserir essa propriedade a força.

Uma forma de fazer isso é fazendo um cast do tipo `Window` para `any`, que é um tipo dinâmico que aceita qualquer propriedade. Então você poderia escrever como

```
(window as any).onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
  // do your spotify magic here.
}
```